# Non-invertible elements in an algebra which do not belong to the kernel of any character

Tags: complex-analysis, functions, commutative-algebra

Is there  a commutative unital algebra $A$ over $\mathbb C$ such that  for some $f\in A$,  $\chi(f)\not=0$  for every (non-zero)
    homomorphism $\chi:A\to\mathbb C$, but for which $f$ is not invertible?  If $A$ is the algebra of rational functions in $\mathbb C$, 
     then this holds, but  in that case there isn't any such character at all. So I ask this question for the case where 
     $X(A)\not=\emptyset$ (the set of all non-zero homomorphisms into $\mathbb C$).
     The algebra of all holomorphic functions in $\mathbb C$ is not such an example, and of course no Banach-algebra has such a `weird' property.

Comment: why does no Banach algebra have such a weird property

Comment: In a commutative unital complex Banach algebra $A$ an element $a\in A$ is invertible if and only if its Gelfand transform $\hat a$ does not vanish on $X(A)$. This is Gelfand's theory and can be found e.g. in Rudin's book ``Real and Complex Analysis".